# java.lang.String error

Tags: arrays, string, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying array dependency using spring this is the code:

Car.java

```
package beans;

public class Car {
private String[] carnames;
private Engine[] engine;

public void setCarnames(String[] carnames) {
    this.carnames = carnames;
}

public void setEngine(Engine[] engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}

public void showData(){
    for(String car:carnames){
        System.out.println(car);
    }

    for(Engine e:engine){
        System.out.println(e.getModelyear());
    }   
}

}
```

Engine.java

```
package beans;

public class Engine {
    private String[] modelyear;

public void setModelyear(String[] modelyear) {
    this.modelyear = modelyear;
}
public String[] getModelyear() {
    return modelyear;
}

}
```

spring.xml

```
        <beans>
          <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
            <property name="modelyear" value="2015"/>
          </bean>

          <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
            <property name="modelyear" value="2016"/>
          </bean>

          <bean id="e3" class="beans.Engine">
            <property name="modelyear" value="2017"/>
          </bean>

          <bean id="c" class="beans.Car">
            <property name="carnames">
              <list>
              <value> Audi</value>
              <value> BMW</value>
              <value> Mercedece</value>

              </list>       
            </property>

            <property name="engine">
            <list>
            <ref bean="e1"/>
            <ref bean="e2"/>
            <ref bean="e3"/>
            </list>
            </property>


          </bean>

        </beans>
```

main method

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Car;

public class Arry_DI_Main { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext ap= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resource/spring.xml");
    Car c=(Car) ap.getBean("c");
    c.showData();

   }
   }
```

and the output is this

```
 Audi

 BMW

 Mercedece

[Ljava.lang.String;@25bbe1b6

[Ljava.lang.String;@5702b3b1

[Ljava.lang.String;@69ea3742
```

why car name is proper but the model year is printing some string..
it should print it's assigned values what's wrong iin this..??

Comment: You have declared your model year as `String[]`, yet you are providing only one value that is not a list?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment ccould you plz elaborate it..??.??

Comment: it's nothing to do with Spring, the issue  is in how you print your data: `System.out.println(e.getModelyear());` will first call toString() method on result of getModelyear() which is  Array<String>. And toString() on array is implemented exactly in the way you see it.